# How to mount ramdrive in 13.10 for fast drive space

Tags: mount, 13.10, ram, drive

trying to mount ramdrive in 13.10 for fast drive space
tmpfs /media/ramdisk  tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777,nosuid,size=1600M 0 0
will not mount properly drive icon shows but will not open drive

Answer (score 0):

Instead, create that ramdrive with

> tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nodev,nosuid,noexec,mode=1777,size=1.6G 0 0

Comment: thanks for that but when I run that command line ubuntu 13.10 will not boot and saids that there are missing plymouth files